# How to add a custom build type to CMake? (targeting make)

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to add a custom build type for my CMake configuration targeting code coverage.

The method I've tried so far is from [the FAQ entry about it in the CMake wiki site](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/FAQ#how-can-i-specify-my-own-configurations-for-generators-that-allow-it-). However, I can't make it work.

Here is my code, using CMake 2.8.5:

```
message("* Adding build types...")
if(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
   list(APPEND CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES CodeCoverage)
   list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
   set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES "${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES}" CACHE STRING
       "Add the configurations that we need"
       FORCE)
   message("  Available build types are now : ${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES}")
else()
   message("  XXX custom build types are not allowed...")
endif()
```

And I get "XXX custom build types are not allowed..."...

Comment: related: [How can I copy all build type parameters from an existing build configuration type to a new build type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75823363/11107541)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Found the problem : there is a confusion between adding custom **builds** and custom **configurations** :

- **configurations** are for special tools like Visual Studio or XCode
- **build types** are a much rawer feature

So to add a custom build type, there is no need to manipulate the CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES variable at all. Just set the corresponding variables and start using it, as [explained](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/FAQ#how-can-i-extend-the-build-modes-with-a-custom-made-one-) :

```
SET(GCC_DEBUG_FLAGS "-g -Wall")

# Add new build types
message("* Adding build types...")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_COVERAGE
    "${GCC_DEBUG_FLAGS} -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage"
    CACHE STRING "Flags used by the C++ compiler during coverage builds."
    FORCE )
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_COVERAGE
    "${GCC_DEBUG_FLAGS} -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage"
    CACHE STRING "Flags used by the C compiler during coverage builds."
    FORCE )
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_COVERAGE
    ""
    CACHE STRING "Flags used for linking binaries during coverage builds."
    FORCE )
SET(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_COVERAGE
    ""
    CACHE STRING "Flags used by the shared libraries linker during coverage builds."
    FORCE )
MARK_AS_ADVANCED(
    CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_COVERAGE
    CMAKE_C_FLAGS_COVERAGE
    CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_COVERAGE
    CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_COVERAGE )
```

We may also want to udate the help string (along with [setting the default build type](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/FAQ#how-can-i-change-the-default-build-mode-and-see-it-reflected-in-the-gui) by the way) :

```
IF(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
   SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug
       CACHE STRING "Choose the type of build : None Debug Release RelWithDebInfo MinSizeRel Coverage."
       FORCE)
ENDIF(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
message("* Current build type is : ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}")
```

A bit of warning about trying to inherit default options from another build type doing this :

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_COVERAGE
    "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage"
    CACHE STRING "Flags used by the C++ compiler during coverage builds."
    FORCE )
```

This is a  **bad** idea because the extra options keep being appended every time the config is sourced again (every time you change something in it).

Comment: You can inherit default options from another build type, but you should not @set(..CACHE...FORCE)@ the composite variable, or you will see this appending behaviour. The variable value that gets propagated into your Makefile does not have to be cached.

Comment: A more recent answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24470998/1938798) gives a more complete and technically correct explanation of this topic.

Comment: I don't understand the "correct" explanation. This one is clear and concise.

Comment: "_This is a bad idea because the extra options keep being appended every time the config is sourced again (every time you change something in it)._" I don't see why that would happen in the code you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

Your if-else went to the else block because that's exactly what's supposed to happen. See [the `if()` command docs for basic expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#basic-expressions). `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES` is not a boolean constant in CMake and it's not a quoted string, so the variable path is taken, and the variable `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES` is typically not defined to a value that evaluates to a falsy constant (unless you did that manually, which I can't see a reason why anyone would ever do).

Note that you don't have to modify `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES` to *define* a custom build type. The purpose of the variable is to list configurations to generate for a buildsystem when using a multi-config generator.

To define a custom build/configuration type, all you need to do is what is already stated [one section down in the wiki page you linked](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/FAQ#how-can-i-extend-the-build-modes-with-a-custom-made-one-)- I.e. define the variables as you would like them which are named in [the reference documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-variables.7.html) with template names containing "`<CONFIG>`" (`cmake --help-variable-list | grep "<CONFIG>"`).