# Is CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_PROFILE deprecated in CMake?

Tags: cmake

I am maintaining an old project, and find following statements in `CMakeList.txt`:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_PROFILE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pg") 
set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_PROFILE "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -pg")
```

But I can't find these variable definitions in my current `cmake`:

```
# cmake --help-variable-list | grep PROFILE
#
```

My `cmake` version is `3.7.2`:

```
# cmake --version
cmake version 3.7.2

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

So are `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_PROFILE` and `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_PROFILE` deprecated? If they existed, what is the function of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we are talking about `makefile` generators you can just do

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Profile ..
```

Anyone can invent new configuration types in their project as in this case it seems to have been done.

Just a hint: The code could even be simplified since the flags will anyway be concatenated like `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` + `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_PROFILE`.

**Reference**

- [How to add a custom build type to cmake ? (targetting make)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437692/how-to-add-a-custom-build-type-to-cmake-targetting-make)
- [Cmake generators for Visual Studio do not set CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31661264/cmake-generators-for-visual-studio-do-not-set-cmake-configuration-types)
- [Is Cmake set variable recursive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828855/is-cmake-set-variable-recursive)