# How to create a CMake configuration type that inherits from Release

Tags: c++, c, cmake

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11437693/160206) describes how to create a custom configuration type from scratch. How can I make a configuration type that exactly matches the builtin `Release`, only with some added flags? I'm using this right now:

```
set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES "Debug;Release;ReleaseWithAssertions" CACHE STRING
    "Available build-types: Debug, Release and ReleaseWithAssertions")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASEWITHASSERTIONS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} 
    -DENABLE_ASSERTIONS=1")
```

This seems to do what I want, but I'm only copying the value of `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE`, so I'm wondering if there is anything I'm missing that users might expect?

Comment: A related question with seemingly a bit more awareness as to how build configuration type definitions work: [https://stackoverflow.com/q/75823363/11107541](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75823363/11107541)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only other one you might want would be CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE in case you're compiling any `C` files.

See cmake's [documentation](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables):

```
None (CMAKE_C_FLAGS or CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS used)
Debug (CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG or CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG)
Release (CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE or CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE)
RelWithDebInfo (CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO or CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
MinSizeRel (CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL or CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL)
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't spotted that part!

Answer (score 5):

No, not in respect of adding a custom "configuration type that exactly matches the builtin `Release`". That's more like a [feature request for CMake](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#I_want_a_new_feature_in_CMake._What_should_I_do.3F).

**Edit**: Just have seen that there actually is a ["Creating new configurations for MSVC" feature request](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/5811) you could give support.

Here is some background information what's possible and what's not:

1. There are potentially many configuration specific variables. You could copy those with a script:

   ```
   get_directory_property(_vars VARIABLES)
   foreach(_var IN LISTS _vars)
       if (_var MATCHES "_RELEASE$")
           string(REPLACE "_RELEASE" "_RELEASEWITHASSERTIONS" _var_new "${_var}")
           set(${_var_new} "${${_var}}")
       endif()
   endforeach()
   ```
2. You need to map imported targets to for your new configuration with setting  [`CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_<CONFIG>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_CONFIG.html):

   ```
   list(APPEND CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_RELEASEWITHASSERTIONS "Release" "")
   ```
3. You can't do anything about `$<CONFIG:cfg>` type [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) checking for specific configuration names
4. You have to check directory/target/source file and configuration specific changes in [properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html)

**References**

- [Is Cmake set variable recursive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828855/is-cmake-set-variable-recursive)
- [What's the CMake syntax to set and use variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037882/whats-the-cmake-syntax-to-set-and-use-variables)

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful information. The solution described by @dlasalle works in my current project, but your answer provides some useful resources to know what to look out for.

Comment: This is so bad(Cmake way). So much work to create a custom build type with one additional preprocessor macro for public release. It should be 2 lines: one to create new build type from currently existing, and the other one to add the property to it. Thanks for the solution, I guess I'll have to write all this just to add custom build type with one preprocessor macro.

Comment: @KulaGGin yes, it's a lot of lines, but it could be factored into a `function()` for reuse. Besides, without knowing more of your context, what you're describing sounds more like it could/should be achieved with `option()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

From https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/FAQ#how-can-i-extend-the-build-modes-with-a-custom-made-one-

It seems you would want to do the same for all of these.

```
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASEWITHASSERTIONS
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASEWITHASSERTIONS
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASEWITHASSERTIONS
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASEWITHASSERTIONS
```