# CMake own configuration type inheritance

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

In my CMake script I'm adding a custom configuration type like suggested in the [CMake FAQ](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/FAQ#how-can-i-specify-my-own-configurations-for-generators-that-allow-it-):

```
if(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
  set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES Debug Release MyRelease)
  set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES "${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES}" CACHE STRING "Reset the configurations to what we need" FORCE)
endif()
```

I would like to have a MyRelease configuration in my generated Visual Studio 2015 project that behaves like Release but with an additional post-build step. The problem is, that it appears to use the Debug configuration as the basis by default. This, in turn, becomes a problem when using imported targets that don't explicitly specify the library location for my own configuration type. For example, when using the imported target `opencv_core` it will try to link against the opencv_core2413**d**.lib which is defined specifically for Debug configuration.

Is there a way to let custom configuration types inherit from the Release configuration type?

Note: I'm using CMake version 3.12.

Comment: You are probably looking for [CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_<CONFIG>](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_CONFIG.html) which affects on choosing of an IMPORTED target's configuration for your configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, do you have any example on how to use the  CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_<CONFIG> variable? I tried setting it like this: `set(CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_MYRELEASE MyRelease Release)` but without luck.

Comment: This sounds like two questions in one. I'd ask for a split, or vote close needs focus, but there's an existing question where the top answer should address both your questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43746829/11107541).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a CMake configuration type that inherits from Release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43746829/how-to-create-a-cmake-configuration-type-that-inherits-from-release)