# How can I copy all build type parameters from an existing build configuration type to a new build type?

Tags: cmake

In CMake (ver. 3.8+), I'd like to copy all the settings for a build type to my custom build type.

I define a custom build type as:

```
# Add new configuration
set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES ${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES} Deploy)
message("generated with config types:" ${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES})
```

Ideally, I would not like to copy manually flags etc. because I may for example copy the CXX and linker flags, but forget C flags.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to copy all the the variables with `<CONFIG>` in their template name in the documentation.

You could hardcode it, or you could be fancy and write a function that does it based on the documented list of such variables. The following function takes the name of a source and destination ("from" and "to") build type names, and uses the output of `cmake --help-variable-list` to copy those source variables to the destination variables:

```
execute_process(
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --help-variable-list
  OUTPUT_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_var_full_list.txt"
)
file(STRINGS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_var_full_list.txt" VAR_FULL_LIST)
foreach(var ${VAR_FULL_LIST})
  if("${var}" MATCHES "<CONFIG>")
    if("${var}" MATCHES "<LANG>")
      foreach(lang C CXX CSharp CUDA OBJC OBJCXX Fortran HIP ISPC Swift ASM ASM_NASM ASM_MARMASM ASM_MASM ASM-ATT)
        # (supported languages list from https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html)
        string(REPLACE "<LANG>" "${lang}" lang_var "${var}")
        list(APPEND CONFIG_VAR_LIST "${lang_var}")
      endforeach()
    else()
      list(APPEND CONFIG_VAR_LIST "${var}")
    endif()
  endif()
endforeach()
unset(VAR_FULL_LIST)

function(copy_configuration_type config_from config_to)
  string(TOUPPER "${config_from}" config_from)
  string(TOUPPER "${config_to}" config_to)
  foreach(config_var ${CONFIG_VAR_LIST})
    string(REPLACE "<CONFIG>" "${config_from}" config_var_from "${config_var}")
    string(REPLACE "<CONFIG>" "${config_to}"   config_var_to   "${config_var}")
    set("${config_var_to}" "${${config_var_from}}" PARENT_SCOPE)
  endforeach()
endfunction()
```

Example usage:

```
copy_configuration_type(DEBUG DEBUG2)
message("CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG2: ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG2}")
```

The wiki page sets these as cache variables (see the [related CMake wiki entry](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/FAQ#how-can-i-extend-the-build-modes-with-a-custom-made-one-)). I didn't do that here, but you could adjust the call to `set()` to do so. If you do, you might also want to add logic for copying whether the cache variable is [marked as advanced](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_cache/ADVANCED.html).

You may also want to copy whether the config is considered a debug configuration (see [the `DEBUG_CONFIGURATIONS` global property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/DEBUG_CONFIGURATIONS.html) (currently only used for a lesser-known feature of `target_link_libraries`, so you might not need to for your use-case))

Related questions: [How to add a custom build type to CMake? (targeting make)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11437692/11107541) and [How to create a CMake configuration type that inherits from Release](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43746829/11107541).

I raised an issue ticket to Kitware requesting that a standard function be added to do this here: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/24632.

Comment: maybe this will affect the output folder used too? Like that the Debug2 executable will be written in the Debug output folder?

Comment: For my use case (VS code with VS toolchain) I ended up filtering the output directories using: `if (NOT "${config_var_to}" MATCHES "OUTPUT_DIRECTORY")`

Comment: @AndrewBloom that's a good point, but do note that by default, those output directory properties are left empty (you can add `set("${config_var_to}" "${${config_var_from}}")` then `message("${config_var_from}": "${${config_var_from}}")` to see for yourself) to signify that CMake will just generate as conventional for the buildsystem type.

Comment: yes, indeed that's exactly what I did, and the *OUTPUT_DIRECTORY* variables where empty strings. I'm not sure if it may be a bug of vscode-cmake-tools or there's a way to distinguish a variable not set vs an empty string. Anyway, thanks for your very useful answer!

Comment: @AndrewBloom It's not really a matter of whether the variable is set or not, since once you read a target property into a variable... the variable will be set. What you're looking for is [`if("${foo}" STREQUAL "")`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#strequal).