# How to add a custom build type to cmake?

Tags: cmake

I want to add my build type to cmake to call cmake like this:

`cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=mytype`

I've written strings to my CMakeLists.txt:

`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-fPIC -o0 -g")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MYTYPE "-fPIC -o0 -g -m32)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-fPIC -o3)`

But cmake uses compiler flags which were wrote in `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG`.

What I should do to add my build type correctly?

Comment: See [this](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_can_I_extend_the_build_modes_with_a_custom_made_one_.3F) for more details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a custom build type to cmake ? (targetting make)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437692/how-to-add-a-custom-build-type-to-cmake-targetting-make)

Comment: It's the same quesion, but that question doesn't give answer.

Comment: Actually it has a good answer that also contains a few links to online resources from which you can get even more details. What's wrong exactly with it?

Comment: Current information is insufficient for determine what is wrong. Provide [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

I've fond soulution. `set` function must be before `project()` directive.